# react-native's borderRadius makes backgroundColor transparent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is normal Screen : 
[image: normal]

This is abnormal Screen : 
[image: abnormal]

The property **borderRadius** affect **backgroundColor** , I really don't know what the problem is.

**Please help me solve this problem.**

This is my components **Panel.js**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        margin:$F.scale(10),
        // borderRadius:$F.scale(3),
        paddingLeft:$F.scale(8),
        paddingRight:$F.scale(8),
    },
    contTitle:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        paddingTop:$F.scale(10),
        paddingBottom:$F.scale(10),
        marginBottom:$F.scale(10),
        alignItems:'center',
        borderBottomWidth:$F.compatiblePixel*1,
        borderBottomColor:'#DFDFDF',
    },
    cont:{
        flex:1,
        paddingBottom:$F.scale(10),

    },
    rightHeader:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:"row",
        justifyContent:'flex-end',
        // backgroundColor:"#444444",
    }
});

   <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.contTitle}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:$F.scale(13),color:"#000000",flex:1}}>{this.state.titleCont}</Text>
        <SelectOption 
            options={this.state.selOptions} 
            onSelectOptions={this._ChooseList.bind(this)} 
            selectShow={this.props.rightHeader?false:this.props.selectShow}  
        />
        <View style={[{display:this.props.rightHeader?"flex":"none"},styles.rightHeader]}>
            {
                this.props.rightHeader
            }
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.cont} >
        {this.props.children}
    </View>
  </View>
```

I use in **learnning.js**

```
<ScrollView  style={[this.props.style,styles.container]}>
        <Panel titleCont="学习轨迹" selectShow={false}> 
        <View style={styles.progressItems}>
            <View style={styles.Line}></View>
            <View style={styles.progressBox}>
            {this.state.learningData.map((v,i)=>{
              return (
                  <ProcessBox key={v.id}>
                  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" activeOpacity={1} onPress={()=>{this._getClassifyId(v.secondClassifyId,v.id)}}>
                    <View style={styles.learnLesson}>
                        <View  style={styles.lessonImg} >
                            <Image source={{uri:IMGHEADURL+v.cover}}  style={styles.Image}/>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.lessonMsg}>
                              <Text style={{fontSize:$F.scale(7.7),color:"#4A4A4A"}}>{v.name}</Text>
                              <Text style={{fontSize:$F.scale(6),color:"#BBBBBB",marginBottom:$F.scale(5.5)}}>{formatTime(v.hasStudy?v.study_time:v.create_time,"full")}</Text>
                              <View style={styles.lessonStatus}>
                                    <View style={[styles.statusItems,styles.status1]}>
                                          <Text style={{fontSize:$F.scale(6.1),color:"#E5E0D0"}}>{v.hasStudy?"练习中":"未练习"}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={[styles.statusItems,styles.status2]}>
                                          <Text style={{fontSize:$F.scale(6.1)}}>{v.firstClassifyName}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={[styles.statusItems,styles.status2]}>
                                          <Text style={{fontSize:$F.scale(6.1)}}>{v.secondClassifyName}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.shareBtn}>
                                    <ICON name="uniE917" size={$F.scale(8.8)} color="#C8C8C8" />
                                    </View>
                              </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </ProcessBox>
              )
            })}

            </View>
        </View>

        </Panel>
      </ScrollView>
```

**The number of cycles is within ten, the style is good, and more than ten the backgroundColor is transeparents.**

Comment: It will be better to give some help if you write your codes related in.

Comment: Do I need to show all the relevant code?